# Problem involving the completion of a general metric space

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

A completion of a metric space $(X,d)$ is a metric space $( \widetilde{X}, \widetilde{d} )$ such that $X \subseteq \widetilde{X}$ and such that:

(I) $\widetilde{d}$ extends $d$.  That is, we have 
$\widetilde{d} (x_{1},x_{2}) = d(x_{1},x_{2})$ for every 
$x_{1},x_{2} \in X$.

(II) $X$ is dense in $\widetilde{X}$. That is, 
$\mbox{cl}(X) = \widetilde{X}$, where the closure is considered with 
respect to the distance $\widetilde{d}$.

(III) The space $( \widetilde{X} , \widetilde{d} )$ is complete.

$\ $

Now here is my problem that I have been trying to attack: Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space, let $(Y,d')$ be a COMPLETE metric space. Suppose there exists an isometry $\varphi :X \rightarrow Y$. Prove that one can construct a completion of $(X,d)$ where $\widetilde{X} := \mbox{cl}\left( \varphi (X) \right) \subseteq Y$.

MY QUESTION:
Okay so I define the set $\widetilde{X} := \mbox{cl}\left( \varphi (X) \right) \subseteq Y$. Now how on earth do I define the distance function $\widetilde{d}$? My guess is to define $\widetilde{d}(\widetilde{x}_{1},\widetilde{x}_{2}) = d'(\widetilde{x}_{1},\widetilde{x}_{2})$ for all $\widetilde{x}_{1},\widetilde{x}_{2} \in \widetilde{X} \subseteq Y$. In this way, $\widetilde{d}$ is the restriction of $d'$ to $\widetilde{X} \times \widetilde{X}$.

But when I do this, nothing works out! Is this the right distance function to use? I am very confused.

EDIT: I misinterpreted something in this problem. What I am actually supposed to do is $identify$ $\widetilde{X}$ with the subset $\mathrm{cl}\left(\varphi(X)\right)$ of $Y$.

Comment: Since $\psi$ is an isometry we have $d(x,y)=d'(\psi (x),\psi (y))$ .

Comment: @user254665 Yes, by definition of an isometry, I should have included that. Another guess I had was $\widetilde{d}(\widetilde{x}_{1},\widetilde{x}_{2})=d(\varphi^{-1}(\widetilde{x}_{1}),\varphi^{-1}(\widetilde{x}_{2}))$. But I don't think this is correct.

Comment: it is correct, if you change your second d to d', and it's the same as mine, Consider the image of (X.d) is an exact copy, including the metric structure ,because the map is an isometry.